# Best practice: Zend View: Load content from database and render PHP-code included in content

Tags: zend-framework, parsing, templates, view

Let's say I load a value from a database which return something like:

```
<?php
//Zend_Controller_Action
public function indexAction()
{
  $dbContent = "<p>Hello <?php echo $user?>!</p>";
  $this->view->paragraph = $dbContent;
}
?>
```

How is it possible, that

```
<?php echo $user?>
```

will be rendered?

What precaution need to be taken (safety issuses, XXS)?

Thanks so much indeed!

**== Edit: ==**
Sorry, I obviously formulated my question misunderstandingly. What I actually ment:

I would like to avoid implementing a template engine like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/%20smarty).

In my project, there will be content that has PHP-Code within a string and that needs to be parsed.

**Example:**

```
<?php
//Zend_Controller_Action
public function indexAction()
{
  $dbContent = "<p>Hello <?php echo $user?>!</p>";
  $this->view->paragraph = $dbContent;
}

<?php
//viewscript.phtml
$user = 'John Doe';
echo $this->paragraph;
?>
```

is supposed to output:

> Hello John Doe!

Is there any *safe* solution to do this without an external template engine?

Thanks once more... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If found a solution [here](http://patrickburke.de/index.php/zend-view-helper-in-database-stored-content), which seems to perfectly fill my needs.

Thanks to all who answered here,

**==UPDATE==**

Unfortunately the posted link is dead. However, the solution was pretty simple. As far as i Remember, it went through the following steps:

1. Fetch content from database and save it in a file
2. Use Zend_Cache to check, whether this file exists
3. If file exists, simply render it. If not, go to step 1.

**==UPDATE II ==**
Found a copy of the page:
[archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20120707080908/http://patrickburke.de/index.php/zend-view-helper-in-database-stored-content)

Comment: This is the second time you ask a question, and answer yourself without upvoting or accepting the answer that the users gives to you. This is a non-sense behavior in my opinion.

Comment: Dear Aurelio, isn't the main purpose of stackoverflow to get answers and vote for the _accepted_ answer? I appreciate the answers given here - also yours. But I'm sorry, neither can I accept any of the answers given at this thread nor up-vote any. Simply because neither of them answered my question. I could've just left it like this but I thought it would be _fair_ to let others know that in meantime I did find an answer! Why should this be nonsense?! Also: I can only vote for my own answer as accepted answer after two days, but then I will do so.

Comment: My answer IS a possible answer to your question. Anyway it's true that you can accept only one answer, but you're still able to UPVOTE how many answers you want.

Comment: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" - stackoverflow tells me :-( Sorry.

Comment: This link is now dead. Could you edit your post to contain the actual solution?

Answer (score 1):

In zend framework you will be always be able to print string (or whatever you want) from a controller but it's a **very bad practice**.

You should give the $user value from the **controller** to the view in this way:

```
$this->view->paragraph = $user;
```

and then, in the **view**, have:

```
<p>Hello <?php echo $this->paragraph; ?>!</p>
```

To ensure this code from XSS you should do some check before (before you print the value) like this:

```
$user = strip_tags($user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework doesn't support automatic output escaping , but you can prevent XSS in many ways.

First of all **push all values into view layer** and then print them with a **View Helper** like *Zend\View\Escape* , by default it returns string under *htmlspecialchars()* but you can set a callback function simple with :

```
//view.phtml
$this->setEscape('yourClass','methodName');
$this->setEscape('functionName');
echo $this->escape($this->myGreatDbValue);
```

Sure you can create your custom View Helper for all your need.

Another way is to create a custom View class extending *Zend\View\Abstract* , override __get() magic method and filtering output .

Read documentations for Zend View Helper and Zend Filter: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.html
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html